# R develop packages without installing every time

Tags: r, package

I am developing an R package, but every time I make some modifications
I have to use `R CMD INSTALL` to install it and see if the new version
is working.

I would like to know if there is some easier way to develop a package in R.
Specifically I would like to be able to develop the package without having
to install it every time I want to test it.

If you are familiar with Python and setuptools, I would like to achieve the
same effect you get using
`python setup.py develop`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install `devtools`, then all you need to do is:

```
require(devtools)
load_all("/wherever/your/package/is")
```

It reloads all the changed code in `.R` files, recompiles, links, loads C code and so on.

`devtools` will also compile your documentation, and run checks.

Nothing else comes close for package development.

Comment: `devtool` is the definitely the way to go. One additional remark: if you use RStudio there is a `build` tab in the upper right window. The `Load All` line in the `more` dropdown will execute the code @Spacedman outlined.